# a question about abstract algebra,the order of $\Bbb Z_{5}[x]/ (x^3+x+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, finite-rings

Firstly, I have proven that $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_{5}[x]$,then how can I know the order of $$\Bbb Z_{5}[x]/ (x^3+x+1),$$ where $(x^3+x+1)$ means the ideal generated by $x^3+x+1$.

Can osmeone give me some help?

Comment: What does order mean here?

Comment: how many elements in the $Z_{5}[x]/(x^3+x+1)$?

Comment: I think that the number of elements. Which I believe must be 125.

Comment: Can you give me some proof

Comment: $(x^3+x+1)$={(x^3+x+1)q(x):any q(x)$\in Z_{5}[x]$ }

Comment: Hint: The quotient ring is a vector space over the field of 5 elements, so if you can find a basis and the cardinality of the basis you will be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that polynomial long division tells us that for any polynomial $f(x)$, it can be uniquely written as $f(x) = q(x)(x^3+x+1) + r(x)$, where $r(x)$ is of degree 2 or less.

This says that the polynomials $ax^2 + bx+c$ form representatives for the equivalence classes in the quotient, allowing the order to be computed.

Comment: Beat me to it! +1

Comment: Beat me too it too. +1

Comment: Oh, it should be 125

Answer (score 1):

More generally, $$\left|\frac{\mathbb F_p[x]}{\text{ <an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over } \mathbb F_p>}\right|=p^n$$

Comment: Oh,thank you for your answer!